# How to pass SQL as file with parameters to Airflow Operator

Tags: airflow

I have an Operator in Airflow:

```
import_orders_op = MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(
    task_id='import_orders',
    mysql_conn_id='con1',
    google_cloud_storage_conn_id='con2',
    provide_context=True,
    sql="""SELECT * FROM orders where orderid>{0}""".format(parameter),
    bucket=GCS_BUCKET_ID,
    filename=file_name,
    dag=dag)
```

Now, the actual query I need to run is 24 rows long. I want to save it in a file and give the operator the path for the SQL file. The operator support this but I'm not sure what to do with the parameter the SQL is needed.

Suggestions?

**EDIT:
This is my code:**

```
import_orders_op = MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(
    task_id='import_orders',
    mysql_conn_id='con1',
    google_cloud_storage_conn_id='con2',
    provide_context=True,
    templates_dict={'sql': '/home/ubuntu/airflow/.../orders_op.sql'},
    sql = '{{ templates_dict.sql }}',
    params={'last_imported_id': LAST_IMPORTED_ORDER_ID, 'table_name' :  TABLE_NAME},
    bucket=GCS_BUCKET_ID,
    filename=file_name,
    dag=dag)
```

This gives:

> jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'templates_dict' is undefined

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As you've noticed, the [MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/mysql_to_gcs.py#L43) specifies a `template_ext` with the .sql extension.

First in your `Dag`, specify the path where you put your .sql file

```
dag = DAG('my_dag', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval="30 7 * * *", template_searchpath = ['/home/ubuntu/airflow/.../myfolder'])
```

In the yourfile.sql put your large query.  Notice the `params.ord_id`

```
SELECT * FROM orders where orderid> {{ params.ord_id }}
```

Now in the `sql` argument of the operator, pass the name of the file.

```
import_orders_op = MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(
    task_id='import_orders',
    mysql_conn_id='con1',
    google_cloud_storage_conn_id='con2',
    provide_context=True,
    sql='yourfile.sql',
    params={"ord_id":99},
    bucket=GCS_BUCKET_ID,
    filename=file_name,
    dag=dag)
```

It is important that you don't put a space after that file name. This is because the Jinja templating engine will look for that string ending with `.sql` and if it does, it will treat it as a file rather than as a string.

Comment: I am aware of this... but this doesn't answer how I can pass the parameter I want to be replaced in the SQL query. Notice my example:   `sql="""SELECT * FROM orders where orderid>{0}""".format(parameter)`

Comment: Hey did you mean passing the params in?  Edited answer to show `params` and the query file

Comment: I may be missing something here. The ord_id as you defined here needs to be replace the {0} in the original SQL. Something in the syntax is missing. ?

Comment: @Programmer120 - ok I see your error. I think I see what's missing. I've re-edited.  Please have a look again. With a DAG definition, pass the template_searchpath.  Then in the file itself notice the `params.` and finally in the operator just pass the filename in the `sql` argument.